# Why do I get 429 status code from OpenAI endpoint?

Tags: javascript, discord, openai-api

İ'm new with coding. I tried to make a Discord bot integrated with OpenAI's API but following code does not work:

```js
client.on('messageCreate', async function(message){
    try {
        // Don't respond to yourself or other bots
        if(message.author.bot) return;

        const gptResponse = await openai.createCompletion({
            model: "davinci",
            prompt: 'ChatGPT is a friendly chatbot.',
            temperature: 0.9,
            max_tokens: 100,
            stop: ["ChatGPT:", "Tunee:"],

        })
        message.reply($(gptResponse.data.choices[0].text))

    } catch(err){
        console.log(err)
    }

});
```

I think there is the mistake but I couldn't figure it

Here is the error message:

```
Error: Request failed with status code 429
    at createError (C:\Users\USER\Desktop\Kod Projelerim ve Çalışmalarım\CHATGPT-DISCORD-CHATBOT\node_modules\axios\lib\core\createError.js:16:15)
    at settle (C:\Users\USER\Desktop\Kod Projelerim ve Çalışmalarım\CHATGPT-DISCORD-CHATBOT\node_modules\axios\lib\core\settle.js:17:12)
    at IncomingMessage.handleStreamEnd (C:\Users\USER\Desktop\Kod Projelerim ve Çalışmalarım\CHATGPT-DISCORD-CHATBOT\node_modules\axios\lib\adapters\http.js:322:11)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (node:events:525:35)
    at endReadableNT (node:internal/streams/readable:1359:12)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21)
```

Comment: "HTTP 429 Too Many Requests response status code indicates the user has sent too many requests in a given amount of time", see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/429  or in the OpenAI help: https://help.openai.com/en/articles/6891829-error-code-429-rate-limit-reached-for-requests - from your question it's unclear why you have sent to many requests.

Comment: But it happens when i give it a prompt after running.

Comment: 429 implies "please give it a moment before retry." You should inspect if there is `Retry-After` header (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Retry-After)